# Как исправить сдвиг страницы в HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. В общем, есть две страницы html,
одна у меня есть и вторая:

**Код первой страницы:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Similique at repellat omnis, mollitia quibusdam error perferendis perspiciatis, <br> nemo hic, ut ipsum voluptatem neque aspernatur soluta ex nesciunt tempore ipsam. Veritatis.<br>
</div>
```

**Код второй страницы:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Similique at repellat omnis, mollitia quibusdam error perferendis perspiciatis, <br> nemo hic, ut ipsum voluptatem neque aspernatur soluta ex nesciunt tempore ipsam. Veritatis.<br> Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Similique at repellat omnis, mollitia quibusdam error perferendis perspiciatis, <br> nemo hic, ut ipsum voluptatem neque aspernatur soluta ex nesciunt tempore ipsam. Veritatis.<br> Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Similique at repellat omnis, mollitia quibusdam error perferendis perspiciatis, <br> nemo hic, ut ipsum voluptatem neque aspernatur soluta ex nesciunt tempore ipsam. Veritatis.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor
  sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

И проблема в том что двигается страница, если сравнить одну и другую страницу то они разные из за сдвига.
Так вот как эту проблему можно исправить?

Comment: Они одинаковые, просто думаю из-за появления полосы прокрутки во второй вам кажется, что они разные. Попробуйте убрать полосу прокрутки или добавить в первой. Или я ошибаюсь? :)

Comment: не из-за сдвига, а из-за скролла.

Comment: А по другому можно это исправить? Просто мне нужен эта прокрутка...

Comment: Всё тема закрыта
Решение:
Добавить
body {
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё тема закрыта Решение: Добавить CSS

```
body { 
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```